# Can I import functions into a typescript class file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have Typescript classes that look like this:

```
class WordService implements IWordService {

    wordCreatedById: number = 0;
    wordModifiedById: number = 0;

    static $inject = [
        "$http",
        "$q",
        ...
    ];

    constructor(
        public $http: ng.IHttpService,
        public $q: ng.IQService,
        ...
    ) {

    }

    wordClear = (): void => {
        this.word = null;
        this.wordBase = null;
    }

    ...

}
```

My class files have become very long now as I defined more and more functions
like wordClear.

Is there any way that I could move functions into another file and import them
into my class?

Comment: Are you asking about importing functions from other files or about partially defining classes?

Comment: You can import function from other files, and then you can call such functions from your class methods, but that's not the right way to deal with the problem. Large classes are considered ["a bad smell"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), and you should break such classes into smaller ones.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're asking about using other functions in class definitions this is one way to accomplish it. Let's put this in utilFunctions.ts (or whatever you want to call it.

```
export function wordClear(obj:{word:any, wordBase:any}/*replace with relevant interface*/) :void {
    obj.word = null;
    obj.wordBase = null;
}
```

and then in the class ts file

```
import * as utilFunctions from './utilFunctions'

class WordService implements IWordService {
    ...
    wordClear = ()=>utilFunctions.wordClear(this);
}
```

Or

```
import * as utilFunctions from './utilFunctions'

class WordService implements IWordService {
    ...
    public wordClear() {
        utilFunctions.wordClear(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `wordClear()` has argumets to be passed?

Comment: The class member is a wrapper function. Like any wrapper function, you can manually pass through the parameters (`public wordClear(thing: object) {`) and then call `utilFunctions.wordClear(this, thing);`.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `.bind` to do [partial application](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Partial_application). This is more useful if your parameters are unknown or changing.